# Pro*c Installation on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu.Can anybody please tell me the soft wares which I need to install on my system before running a pro*c program.Giving step by step procedure with commands would help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to  this ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C

Comment: Yes.That is the one I am talking about.